# Compressing multiple images before uploading them to firebase android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, image-compression

I am working on application users have to upload multiple images. Now the problem I am facing is their size. As users can upload multiple images it takes a lot of time to upload them through the application because of their heavy size which users do not like and also make my application and database heavy. Can you please guide me on how can I compress multiple images before uploading them to firebase?

**CODE TO COMPRESS IMAGES**

```
  galleryResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {


                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && null != result.getData() ) {

                    if (result.getData().getClipData() != null) {

                        int countofImages = result.getData().getClipData().getItemCount();
                        //this part is to select multiple images
                        for (int i = 0; i < countofImages; i++) {

                            if (uri.size() < 11) {
                                Uri imageuri = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();


                              
                                imageList.add(new CustomModel(getfilename(imageuri), imageuri));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't select more than 11 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        //then notify the adapter
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        rentSell3Binding.totalphotos.setText("Photos (" + imageList.size() + ")");
                    }
                        //this part is to select single image
                        else
                            {

                            if (uri.size()<11) {
                                Uri imageuri = result.getData().getData();

                                //and add the code to arryalist
                         
                                imageList.add(new CustomModel(getfilename(imageuri), imageuri));

                            }else
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't select more than 11 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        //notify the adapter
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        rentSell3Binding.totalphotos.setText("Photos (" + imageList.size() + ")");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You haven't selected any images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }


    });
```

**MODEL CLASS**

```
public class CustomModel {

String imageName;
Uri imageURI;


public CustomModel(String imageName, Uri imageURI) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.imageURI = imageURI;
}

public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}

public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}

public Uri getImageURI() {
    return imageURI;
}

public void setImageURI(Uri imageURI) {
    this.imageURI = imageURI;
}
```

}

**Throwing exception**

```
null pointer exception on the line File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp")));
```

Comment: @blackapps yes i can resize one image

Comment: @blackapps please check the code

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: @yes throwing null pointer exception

Comment: What is a null pointer exception? Why didnt you ask directly in your post how to solve a null pointer exception? You did not even mention it.

Comment: sorry for that but the problem is that i am not sure that the code i write for compress is correct or not

Comment: You should post more of the stacktrace as it exactly tells you which pointer is null. You did not tell us which pointer is null. Read the logcat!

Comment: ok but do you think the  code i wrote for the compress it correct?

Comment: That is irrelevant at the moment. First handle the exception.

Comment: ok thank you i do check

Comment: @blackapps i checked and found that the problem was in the compress library i was using so i just removed that code and now it is my code without compression i am using

Comment: now can you guide me how can i achieve compression  with any other library

Comment: If you mean: resize the image files so their resolution becomes less and so their -file- size then you have already an answer. And i'm puzzled as you first comment is `@blackapps yes i can resize one image`.

Comment: so i was using a method to resize single image but it was not good at all that's why i told you that.. but now i am clueless completely

Comment: @blackapps can you please check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73845925/how-can-i-show-my-filtered-data-on-another-screen-in-android

Answer (score 0):

yup, you can compress your image file by the following function

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun File.compressImage(
    reqWidth: Float,
    reqHeight: Float,
    compressFormat: Bitmap.CompressFormat,
    quality: Int,
    destinationPath: String
): File {
    var fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    val file = File(destinationPath).parentFile ?: return File(destinationPath)

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs()
    }
    try {
        fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(destinationPath)
        // write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by destinationPath.
        decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(this, reqWidth, reqHeight)?.compress(
            compressFormat,
            quality,
            fileOutputStream
        )
    } finally {
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            fileOutputStream.flush()
            fileOutputStream.close()
        }
    }

    return File(destinationPath)
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(
    imageFile: File,
    reqWidth: Float,
    reqHeight: Float
): Bitmap? {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions

    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    var bmp: Bitmap? = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.absolutePath, options)

    var actualHeight = options.outHeight
    var actualWidth = options.outWidth

    var imgRatio = actualWidth.toFloat() / actualHeight.toFloat()
    val maxRatio = reqWidth / reqHeight

    if (actualHeight > reqHeight || actualWidth > reqWidth) {
        // If Height is greater
        when {
            imgRatio < maxRatio -> {
                imgRatio = reqHeight / actualHeight
                actualWidth = (imgRatio * actualWidth).toInt()
                actualHeight = reqHeight.toInt()
            } // If Width is greater
            imgRatio > maxRatio -> {
                imgRatio = reqWidth / actualWidth
                actualHeight = (imgRatio * actualHeight).toInt()
                actualWidth = reqWidth.toInt()
            }
            else -> {
                actualHeight = reqHeight.toInt()
                actualWidth = reqWidth.toInt()
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight)
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false

    if (bmp != null && canUseForInBitmap(bmp, options)) {
        // inBitmap only works with mutable bitmaps, so force the decoder to
        // return mutable bitmaps.
        options.inMutable = true
        options.inBitmap = bmp
    }
    options.inTempStorage = ByteArray(16 * 1024)

    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.absolutePath, options)
    } catch (exception: OutOfMemoryError) {
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }

    var scaledBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    } catch (exception: OutOfMemoryError) {
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }

    val ratioX = actualWidth / options.outWidth.toFloat()
    val ratioY = actualHeight / options.outHeight.toFloat()
    val middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f
    val middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f

    val scaleMatrix = Matrix()
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY)

    val canvas = Canvas(scaledBitmap!!)
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix)
    canvas.drawBitmap(
        bmp!!, middleX - bmp.width / 2,
        middleY - bmp.height / 2, Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG)
    )
    bmp.recycle()
    val exif: ExifInterface
    try {
        exif = ExifInterface(imageFile.absolutePath)
        val orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0)
        val matrix = Matrix()
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90f)
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180f)
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270f)
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.width,
            scaledBitmap.height, matrix, true
        )
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return scaledBitmap
}

private fun calculateInSampleSize(
    options: BitmapFactory.Options,
    reqWidth: Int,
    reqHeight: Int
): Int {
    // Raw height and width of image
    val height = options.outHeight
    val width = options.outWidth
    var inSampleSize = 1

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2
        val halfHeight = height / 2
        val halfWidth = width / 2

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while (halfHeight / inSampleSize >= reqHeight && halfWidth / inSampleSize >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize
}

/**
 * Ref: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory#kotlin
 */
private fun canUseForInBitmap(candidate: Bitmap, targetOptions: BitmapFactory.Options): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // From Android 4.4 (KitKat) onward we can re-use if the byte size of
        // the new bitmap is smaller than the reusable bitmap candidate
        // allocation byte count.
        val width: Int = targetOptions.outWidth / targetOptions.inSampleSize
        val height: Int = targetOptions.outHeight / targetOptions.inSampleSize
        val byteCount: Int = width * height * getBytesPerPixel(candidate.config)
        byteCount <= candidate.allocationByteCount
    } else {
        // On earlier versions, the dimensions must match exactly and the inSampleSize must be 1
        candidate.width == targetOptions.outWidth &&
                candidate.height == targetOptions.outHeight &&
                targetOptions.inSampleSize == 1
    }
}

/**
 * A helper function to return the byte usage per pixel of a bitmap based on its configuration.
 */
private fun getBytesPerPixel(config: Bitmap.Config): Int {
    return when (config) {
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 -> 4
        Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 -> 2
        Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8 -> 1
        else -> 1
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Context.createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "JPEG_${System.currentTimeMillis()}_", /* prefix */
        ".jpg", /* suffix */
        storageDir /* directory */
    )
}
```

and simply call the following method to create compressed image file. here file is you image file

```
file.compressImage(
                    1024f,
                    1024f,
                    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                    70,
                    context.createImageFile().path
                )
```

Comment: can you please provide code for java??