# How can i show my filtered data on another screen in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-search

I am working on an app where at my home fragment I have a searchview under that there is a recyclerview where I am showing the whole data but when user uses searchview and search for any data now I want to show the data to another fragment, Ho can I achieve that?? please guide me

IMAGE[image]

**CODE FOR SEARCH ON HOME FRAGMENT**

```
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                pd.setTitle("Searching");
                pd.show();

                Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        search(query);
                        pd.cancel();
                    }
                };

                Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
                pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                if (newText.isEmpty())
                {
                    getData();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    getDataCompleteData();
    
}



//SEARCH METHOD
private void search(String s) {

     mydatalist = new ArrayList<>();

    for (RecyclerviewModel object : datalist) {
        if (object.getSearching().contains(s.toLowerCase().trim())) {
            mydatalist.add(object);
        }

        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(mydatalist, getContext(), HomeFragment.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

**THIS IS MY CODE FOR SEARCH ON HOME FRAGMENT BUT THIS CODE SHOWS THE FILTERED(SEARCHED DATA) ON THE SAME FRAGMENT, I WANT THAT WHEN USER ENTER A QUERY IN SEARCHVIEW, THEN SEARCHED DATA SHOULD BE SHOWN ON THE NEW FRAGMENT.**

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement i can not able to understand your actual approach to show the data.
As i understand this approach to do the same don't know this will fulfil your requirement which you're looking for.

You can transfer data between fragments using bundle.
After user search any value you will get the filtered list from the main data list, now you can pass this filtered list using the code below to put when you get the filtered list from your search function in your case you have mydatalist in your search function. Make sure to create your data class of the list Serializable.

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list", mydatalist); 
    
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
    
    getFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(<Your container id>, fragment2)
          .commit();
```

Now in your second fragment get the list like the code below and set as per your requirement.

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    
    if(bundle != null){
         // handle your code here.
         <Your List Type> = listbundle.getParcelableArrayList("list");
    }
```

Comment: hey khush thank you for your response so it is like i have fragment A where you can see that my all data is showing so when user search for something so now i just want to show the filtered data on the new fragment, not on the same

Comment: Yes, for that you must need to make a fragment transaction from your Fragment A to your Fragment B and you can pass your filtered data list using bundle while transaction occurs in between fragments.I had provided this same code flow above.

Comment: hey khush bhai thank you your solution is right the only problem is that i am using navigation component where it is not working

Comment: can you please guide me for the same on navigation component

Comment: You can pass data between fragments using Arguments while transacting in navigation components please find this link :- https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data
If you find any challenges in the same after looking and implementing in it you can ask me..

Comment: brother it is not passing ArrayList<Model> to the next fragment

Comment: i am using safe args

Comment: You must need to make your model class parcelable for that while passing the list you can pass model containing whole data. Also add arguments of the model class type.

Comment: Please use default navigation component functionality which is way more better.

Comment: i have done that brother

Comment: Okay still you are facing issue then must check your argument type is of the same model class i think this will solve the issue.

Comment: yes that is the case safe args does not support Arralist<Model> argument type

Comment: it only support Model Class type

Comment: bhai tell me one thing if you are retriving data from firebase in list<Model> type and now want to pass this data to the next fragment to set this on the recyclerview how wiill you do that

Comment: You can create another model containing your list<model> and then pass this model class. Create it as like this FinalModel(finalData : List<Your Model>) and then pass this FinalModel.

Comment: If you still facing any issue refer this good example :- https://www.raywenderlich.com/19327407-using-safe-args-with-the-android-navigation-component

Comment: brother problem is how to pass, i have used viewmodel it is also showing problem

Comment: Edit question with all the details so that i can understand your flow and provide you the exact answer.

Comment: ok brother this is the link of viewmodel i have used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881373/how-to-make-viewmodel-variable-assesible-outside-method-in-android

Comment: please check bhai